# Dynamic Arrays in VB

Tags: vb.net

Struggling student here... I've been asked to find the min, max and mid-point value. However, I cannot figure this out; arrays/data storage is 3 chapters away. So, I'm hoping someone could help me out with this conundrum.

-I need to get the data from an individual element within an array in decimal. Any ideas? I've largely been unsuccessful with the 'array.getvalue' method & with the 'array.min' methods.

```
Dim numberOfInvoices As Integer
Dim totalOfInvoices As Decimal
Dim invoiceAverage As Decimal

Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim subtotal As Decimal = CDec(txtEnterSubtotal.Text)
    Dim discountPercent As Decimal = 0.25D
    Dim discountAmount As Decimal = Math.Round(subtotal * discountPercent, 2)
    Dim invoiceTotal As Decimal = subtotal - discountAmount
    Dim minimum, maximum, middle, i As Decimal
    Dim array(1) As Decimal
    Dim midpoint As Integer

    txtSubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(subtotal)
    txtDiscountPercent.Text = FormatPercent(discountPercent, 1)
    txtDiscountAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(discountAmount)
    txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceTotal)

    numberOfInvoices += 1
    totalOfInvoices += invoiceTotal
    invoiceAverage = totalOfInvoices / numberOfInvoices

    For i = 0 To numberOfInvoices - 1
        array(i) = i
        ReDim Preserve array(0 To numberOfInvoices - 1)
    Next i

    If numberOfInvoices = 1 Then
        minimum = totalOfInvoices
        middle = totalOfInvoices
        maximum = totalOfInvoices
    End If

    If numberOfInvoices > 1 Then
        midpoint = numberOfInvoices / 2
        middle = array.GetValue(midpoint)
        For Each i In array
            If i < UBound(array) - 1 Then If array(i) > array(i + 1) Then maximum = array(i)
            If i < UBound(array) - 1 Then If array(i) < array(i + 1) Then minimum = array(i)
        Next i
    End If

    txtLargestInvoice.Text = maximum.ToString
    txtSmallestInvoice.Text = minimum.ToString
    txtMidPoint.Text = middle.ToString
    txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = numberOfInvoices.ToString
    txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = FormatCurrency(totalOfInvoices)
    txtInvoiceAverage.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceAverage)

    txtEnterSubtotal.Text = ""
    txtEnterSubtotal.Select()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnClearTotals_Click(sender As Object,
        e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearTotals.Click
    numberOfInvoices = 0
    totalOfInvoices = 0
    invoiceAverage = 0

    txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = ""
    txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = ""
    txtInvoiceAverage.Text = ""

    txtEnterSubtotal.Select()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnExit_Click(sender As Object,
        e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is for a .NET class?

Comment: Change description of your OP to describe what data you have, what data you need, and what are you doing and/or failing.

Comment: As with any problem, the first step is to work out what you need to do, i.e. the algorithm. That's not even a programming problem because the algorithm should work just as well for pen and paper. Once you have the steps, you can then implement each one in code.  If the code you have doesn't do as you expect, you should be able to describe exactly where and how its behaviour deviates from your expectation. If you can't do that then it's too soon to be posting here.

Comment: `ReDim Preserver` allocates a completely new array, copies the elements from the old to the new, and resassigns your references to the point to the new. It's... not the best way to handle, and really only exists for backwards compatibility with old vb6-era code. These days, you should typically use a List(Of T) instead.

Comment: Also, my experience in the education field tells me when something is still three chapters away, your probably aren't gonna need it for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
        'You can declare and initialize an array in one line
        Dim arr() As Double = {13.5, 18.0, 6.2, 11.8, 13.6}
        'Just check intellisense for a list of methods and properties of arrays
        Dim myAverage As Double = arr.Average()
        Dim myMin As Double = arr.Min
        Dim myMax As Double = arr.Max
        Dim myMedian As Double
        'The original array is lost when .Sort is applied
        Array.Sort(arr)
        Dim myLength As Integer = arr.Length
        'If the lenght of the array is even you could also average 
        'the middle two values And return that number which
        'may not be a value in the original array
        myMedian = arr(CInt(myLength / 2)) 'returns the higher of the middle two if length is even
        'or the actual middle value in the sorted array
        MessageBox.Show($"        The Average value is {myAverage}
        The Maximum value is {myMax}
        The Minimum value is {myMin}
        The Median value is {myMedian}")
    End Sub
```